# Why my php login code always goes to the else statement which is wrong username and password?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php login code where i have problem with my condition. I think.

```
<?php


session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$mysql_database = "practiceLogin";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die ("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");




if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_account WHERE uName = ? AND uPassword = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
$stmt->execute();
$get_result=$stmt->get_result();
$row_count= $get_result->num_rows;

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

if ($row_count>0){
$_SESSION['User_name'] = $username;


echo "Login Success!";
exit();
}else{
echo "Wrong username and password";
exit();
}

}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action = "?" method = "POST">
<input type = "text" name="username"><br>
<input type = "password" name = "password"><br>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login"></br>
<a href = "register.php">Create Account</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Everytime I login to this i always go to the else statment which is `Wrong username and password` always showing up even i have the right credentials? What am I missing?

I don't need to hash my password at this time i just need an answer if i can have a successful login page. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: and this question's a repost of your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112958/why-my-php-code-is-not-working where you made the same error.

Comment: Passwords should be hashed.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use have given `name` to your `password` field to `name = "password"`. But after submit you have been used `$password = $_POST['Password'];`. Use`$_POST['password']`. Thats why you are not getting any `result`.

Also you can select database in single line like

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$databasename);
```

then you don't need to use `mysqli_select_db();`

Comment: even i use `$_POST=['password']` still my code goes to the else statement. :( @mamta

Comment: Then it may be issue in query execution please use this if(!$stmt->execute()) echo $stmt->error; to debug

Comment: Where part of the code should put that sir? Thanks alot sir! :D @mamta

Answer (score 0):

Update your php part & uncomment the commented line so that you can get the exact features:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_account WHERE uName = ? AND uPassword = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
    $get_result=$stmt->get_result();
    //print_r($get_result); //DEBUG purpose 
    $row_count= $get_result->num_rows;
   //print_r($row_count); die;// DEBUG purpose 
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

   if ($row_count>0){
       $_SESSION['User_name'] = $username;
       echo "Login Success!";
       exit();
   }else{
      echo "Wrong username and password";
       exit();
   }

}
```

Comment: `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 10 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) 0` this is whats happening is this alright? @Dipanwita Kundu